# How do you make a function in python for a factorial that is the product of all the positive EVEN integers less than or equal to n using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

def factorial(n):

```
if n == 0:

   return 1

else: 

   return n * factorial(n-2)
```

I can not seem to be able to figure this problem out. I can find the even integers for even factorials, but I can not seem to figure out how to find even integers for odd factorials at the same time. I've been at it for days now.  I am extremely new to python, so any help would be very appreciative. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to calculate this by hand for 5, with what number will you start? For 13? For 25? For some other odd n?

Comment: change your condition to avoid endless loops if you do not hit 0 exactly... do your logic by hand, starting with given n of 3 and you'll see. Also look up the modulo operator `%` to detect even/odd.

Answer (score 0):

This should work!

```
def factorial(n):
    if n % 2 != 0:
        n -= 1
    return 1 if (n < 1) else n * factorial(n-2)
    
print(factorial(6))
print(factorial(7))
```

The output will be:

```
48
48
```

Equals for `n = 6` or `n = 7` (even and odd numbers) as you can see

Comment: It would be more efficient to call `factorial(n-2)`, as `n-1` is guaranteed to be odd.

Comment: @ThierryLathuille It call `factorial(n-2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
factorial = lambda x: functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, range(2, x+1, 2))
```

Use internal method `functools.reduce` to prevent maximum recursion depth

Comment: Worth noting that [`math.prod` was introduced in python3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod) and allows you to write `math.prod(range(2,x+1,2))` instead of `functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, range(2, x+1, 2))`